# addView equivalente but adding Preference to PreferenceScreen?

Tags: java, android

I had recently had to do add a view to a LinearLayout programatically, I have to do the same for a for a PreferenceScreen but I don't know how. This is how it was done for a LinearLayout:

```
    LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService("layout_inflater");
    View myView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    final PreferenceScreen ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutID);
    ll.addView(myView);
```

How can I do the same to add a preference to a PreferenceScreen?

---

EDIT:

This is what I've done so far:

```
Preference preference = new Preference(this);
        preference .setTitle("WHATEVER");
        preference .setSummary("Summary");
        preference .setKey("your_key");
```

I managed to create a preference and store it in list1, I think it's ok so far, but now I need to figure out how to append it inside `<PreferenceScreen id="@+id/list">`?

Comment: I found out about cat.addPreference(preference) I only need to know how to select the correct PreferenceCategory. I'm trying `PreferenceCategory cat = (PreferenceCategory) findViewById(R.id.app_list);` but I don't know how to select a preference by id.

Comment: `findViewById` won't work here, a `PreferenceActivity` has only one view: the `ListView` that holds the preferences.

Comment: I see, so how can I select a PreferenceCategory/PreferenceScreen? I suppose it will be fundamental if I want to append something to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup = (PreferenceGroup) findPreference("containerId");
if (preferenceGroup != null) {
    preferenceGroup.addPreference(myNewPreference);
}
```

same goes for PreferenceScreen (replace PreferenceScreen with each time i've written PreferenceGroup ).